# Dijkstra's handwriting font in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know of a painless way of producing a LaTeX document using Dijkstra's handwriting font?

EDIT:
For those who would like more context on the above question, [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd10xx/EWD1036.PDF) follows a beautiful real-life sample of Edsger Dijkstra's penmanship. A truetype version of it can be found [here](http://lucacardelli.name/Artifacts/Fonts/Pc/dijkstra.ttf).

Comment: At least you could add a little more info so we do not need to google it to see what you are talking about.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `xelatex`/`lualatex` with the `fontspec` package lets you use any TTF/OTF font.

Comment: thanks @TorbjørnT., I finally managed to make it work with `xelatex` and `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: go for me, @Manuel, I am sure you will not regret googling Dijkstra.

Comment: @under-construction Already did. But the question should have (IMO) a little more info. Adding about that font and where to obtain it will help.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, @Manuel, and updated the question following your advice.